# Response 401 when using Credentials AND proxy (calling web service)

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, http-status-code-401, credentials

I using VB.NET 2.0.

I am trying to call a web service. This web service requires authentication. So, I am able to execute the web service when using Credentials only. But, when I add a local proxy (I tried with ezProxy Manager) I get a 401 error.

I need to get this working with a proxy as well. Any ideas why this may fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with this, too. Our proxy server uses our Windows logon credentials, and the changes made to the app.config file for security mode and clienCredentialType elements seems to work for me:

[Calling SharePoint web services using Visual Studio 2008, WCF, and Windows Authentication](http://web.archive.org/web/20100201141922/http://www.trentswanson.com/post/2008/01/Calling-SharePoint-web-services-using-Visual-Studio-20082c-WCF2c-and-Windows-Auth.aspx) (*Archived*)

Comment: @CGK - it does appear that his blog archive no longer goes back five years. And that's my fault?! That's worthy of a down-vote?

Comment: You're right. Edited the answer to add a working link and removed the downvote.